# What reason could prevent console output from "virsh -c qemu:///system console guest1"?

Tags: 10.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm running KVM on a Ubuntu 10.04 host. The guest OS is also Ubuntu 10.04 .

I am attempting to connect to the guest using the 'console' command. It appears I can establish a connection, but I get no output.

```
$ sudo virsh -c qemu:///system console guest1
Connected to domain guest1
Escape character is ^]
(NOTHING HERE)
^]
$
```

I don't have a 'serial' device configured, but I do have these 'console' devices.

```
<console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/2'>
  <source path='/dev/pts/2'/>
  <target port='0'/>
</console>
<console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/2'>
  <source path='/dev/pts/2'/>
  <target port='0'/>
</console>
```

Are these sufficient for a console, or do I need a serial device as well?

What do I need to do in order to get the KVM console to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you do need to configure the guest to use a serial console.  You need three things for this to work:

1. give the guest a virtual serial device of type `pty` (for example by adding one in the `virt-manager` vm info page)
2. tell the kernel to use that for its output, by adding boot parameters like `serial=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8` into `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub`; then run `sudo update-grub`
3. (optional) [put a getty on ttyS0](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9610421&postcount=7) so that you get a login prompt

See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=507650 for more.

Comment: And to add a getty to ttyS0, I followed the instructions here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9610421&postcount=7

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that your virtual machine does not have a serial console configured.

```
virsh dumpxml guest1
```

will show if there is a serial console configured or not. There should be something similar as

```
<serial type='pty'>
<target port='0'/>
</serial>
```

Comment: Thanks @txwikinger . I updated my question with some output from `virsh dumpxml`. I don't see a serial device, but I do see some console devices. Do you know if that is sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is very well explained:

[Serial console for Ubuntu server 10.04 KVM guests](http://koo.fi/tech/2010/11/27/serial-console-for-ubuntu-server-1004-kvm-guests/)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this.

Here is what I have inthe XML config on the host (running KVM):

```
<serial type='pty'>
  <source path='/dev/pts/0'/>
  <target port='0'/>
</serial>
<console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/0'>
  <source path='/dev/pts/0'/>
  <target port='0'/>
</console>
```

I also had to add the following in /etc/default/grub.conf in the VM (append to the "kernel" command):

```
kernel ..... serial=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8
```

Finally I secured the ttyS0 by adding "/etc/securetty" to enable root login from here

```
vi /etc/securetty
ttyS0
```

You might need to muck with your getty settings (as described by the other answer) as well

Hope this helps